# Ado.Net e Entity no mesmo projeto

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Peguei um teste para fazer e é obrigatório o uso de Ado.Net, mas seria um diferencial o uso do Entity. Estou meio confuso quanto a isso. Ado.Net e Entity dá baile?

Comment: Como assim dá baile? báile em usar os dois no mesmo projeto?

Comment: Acredito que você esteja perguntando se os dois juntos funcionam e é correto fazer assim, sim pode utilizar, só precisa dosar e saber fazer mas, funciona sem problemas, inclusive muitos utlizar Entity e Dapper na mesma aplicação.

Comment: dá baile sim cara.. mas sei lá.. eu prefiro ficar com um apenas, tem gente que usa Dapper e EF como o @VirgilioNovic comentou, eu particularmente sou mais adepto ao Dapper, quando a coisa fica complexa no EF e você precisa fazer manutenção em alguma query via Linq prefiro mexer no SQL do que bater cabeça com as lambdas e sintaxes do linq quando você tem relacionamentos enormes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a dúvida é se os dois funcionam juntos, sim os dois podem funcionar juntos

Veja o exemplo que montei

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InserirDados();
        UsandoAdo();
        UsandoEF();
    }

    static void InserirDados()
    {
        using (EFContext ef = new EFContext())
        {
            if (!ef.Pessoas.Any())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    ef.Pessoas.Add(new Pessoa() { Nome = $"Nome {i}" });
                }

                ef.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    static void UsandoAdo()
    {
        using (SqlConnection ado = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFContext"].ToString()))
        {
            string select = "select * from pessoas";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(select, ado);
            ado.Open();
            var dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Usando ADO {dr["Nome"]}");
            }
        }
    }

    static void UsandoEF()
    {
        using (EFContext ef = new EFContext())
        {
            foreach(var pessoa in ef.Pessoas.ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Usando EF {pessoa.Nome}");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
}

public class Pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Adicionei o código fonte do exemplo ao meu [github](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/AdoNetComEntityFramework)